# Troubleshooting Azure App Service Container Deployment

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a dotnet web api into an Azure App Service as a container using the service image from an Azure Container Registry. The following is what I see in logs when I run `az webapp log tail -g myRg -n mywebapp`. I have ServiceConnections to my ACR and the Resource Group wherein my App Service resides, set up in my Azure DevOps project.

```
2023-07-19T15:48:19.096Z INFO  - Pulling image: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/msitokenservice:stage4

2023-07-19T15:48:21.615Z INFO  - stage4 Pulling from appsvc/msitokenservice

2023-07-19T15:48:21.616Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:03ecc0ab47f7e24fc8da61e61a6758250d576f0dda38ef0256cbbd7ecbd096a9

2023-07-19T15:48:21.616Z INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/msitokenservice:stage4
2023-07-19T15:48:23.622Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 2 Seconds

2023-07-19T15:48:23.705Z INFO  - Starting container for site

2023-07-19T15:48:23.713Z INFO  - docker run -d --expose=8081 --expose=49494 --name mywebapp_0_5361e064_msiProxy -e WEBSITE_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=* -e WEBSITE_CORS_SUPPORT_CREDENTIALS=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=mywebapplinkdoesnotexist.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=<someId> -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=False mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/msitokenservice:stage4  
2023-07-19T15:50:04  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2023-07-19T15:51:04  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2023-07-19T15:52:04  No new trace in the past 3 min(s).
....
```

Pipeline:

```
stages:
- stage: Deploy_my_service_stage
  dependsOn: []
  jobs:
    - deployment: my_Service_deployment
      environment: microservices-stage
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
              inputs:
                ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                azureSubscription: My-Service-Connection-Name
                appType: 'webAppContainer'
                WebAppName: 'mywebapp001'
                DockerNamespace: 'myacr.azurecr.io'
                DockerRepository: 'my-repo'
                DockerImageTag: '_mytag'
```

When I try to access my website, all I see is "Application Error" and can't figure out what may have gone wrong. Any pointers to help me troubleshoot this issue would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The image being pulled doesn't match your acr registry. First thing I would do is check your container registry repository to make sure that your pipeline is actually pushing updated images.

[image]

The next thing I would check is the Deployment center settings of your app service. Your app service should be pulling the image from your `myacr.azurecr.io/my-repo:_mytag` container registry, but the logs show it's pulling from `mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/msitokenservice`, which is an image that, according docker hub, hasn't been updated in 5 years. I'm not even sure what it is or what it's supposed to do but I'm betting your application error is related to the that image. Run the image locally and see if it can successfully receive HTTPS requests. Deployment Center also has a Log tab that you can use to confirm the pipeline deployment.